# chromecast BaseCastConsumer OnFailedListener

Tags: android, chromecast

I tried to implement
(https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android) in my project. but couldnot figure out why the process moved to onFailedListener. I've posted the code where I got the problem below.

```
private void setupCastListener() {

    Log.e("BHITRA" ,"SET UP CAST LISTENER");
    mCastConsumer = new VideoCastConsumerImpl() {
        @Override
        public void onApplicationConnected(ApplicationMetadata appMetadata,
                String sessionId, boolean wasLaunched) {

            Log.d(TAG, "onApplicationLaunched() is reached");
            if (null != mSelectedMedia) {

                if (mPlaybackState == PlaybackState.PLAYING) {
                    mVideoView.pause();
                    try {
                        loadRemoteMedia(mSeekbar.getProgress(), true);
                        finish();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Utils.handleException(LocalPlayerActivity.this, e);
                    }
                    return;
                } else {
                    mPlaybackState = PlaybackState.IDLE;
                    updatePlaybackLocation(PlaybackLocation.REMOTE);
                }
            }
            updatePlayButton(mPlaybackState);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onApplicationDisconnected(int errorCode) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onApplicationDisconnected() is reached with errorCode: " + errorCode);
            updatePlaybackLocation(PlaybackLocation.LOCAL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDisconnected() is reached");
            mPlaybackState = PlaybackState.IDLE;
            mLocation = PlaybackLocation.LOCAL;
            updatePlayButton(mPlaybackState);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRemoteMediaPlayerMetadataUpdated() {
            Log.e("BHITRA" ,"1");

            try {
                mRemoteMediaInformation = mCastManager.getRemoteMediaInformation();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // silent
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailed(int resourceId, int statusCode) {

            Log.e("BHITRA" ,"2" + resourceId +"-->"+statusCode );



        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
            Utils.showToast(LocalPlayerActivity.this,
                    R.string.connection_temp_lost);
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectivityRecovered() {
            Utils.showToast(LocalPlayerActivity.this,
                    R.string.connection_recovered);
        }

    };


}
```

The error statusCode shown is -1.

Comment: When do you get that? You need to turn on logging in CCL (set DEBUG=true in LogUtils) and provide logs

Comment: Thank you this helped :)

Comment: error status was shown -1 because i did not declare the VideoCastControllerActivity in the manifest and due to this it was going inside onFailedListener instead of onPause().